# scaleControl: false, is not working. How do I resolve this? Google Maps API 3

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3

This is my current code

```
var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 2,
        minZoom: 4,
        maxZoom: 100,
        streetViewControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: ["custom"]
```

[But as you can see, the controls stay.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHsPJ.png)

I've tried ZoomControl: false, as well but that doesnt work either.

Any idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scaleControl:false is the default value, it controls the [scaleControl](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlModification).  (`scaleControl` enables/disables the Scale control that provides a simple map scale. By default, this control is not visible. When enabled, it will always appear in the bottom right corner of the map.)  If you want the [defaultUI](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#DefaultUI) disabled, set `disableDefaultUI: true`.

If you are just worried about the zoomControl, you don't have any code to disable that (that would be [`zoomControl: false`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions) (**not** `ZoomControl: false`, javascript is case sensitive).

```
var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    zoom: 2,
    minZoom: 4,
    maxZoom: 100,
    zoomControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    scaleControl: false, // this is the default value...
    mapTypeControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
    mapTypeIds: ["custom"]
```

Comment: Thank you! I messed up with the capital Z